# Arabic characters not showing in mail when javamail program run from cmd

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Javamail program run from eclipse it shows Arabic characters in email body but when run from `cmd` , Arabic characters showing like this `ÙŠÙˆØºÙŠØ´ Ù…ÙˆÙ‡ÙŠØª` in email body.

Answer (score 0):

That's because cmd not supports Arabic characters. You can't do it even after changing font of cmd or other tricks. Try to find other way to show emails!